# Including a function in async series

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am using [`twit`](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) package.
The `twit.get` function should return data which will be used to insert data in table.

How do I include `twit.get` in `async` tasks as a function?

```
  var tweet=new twit(config);
  var asyncTasks = [];       
  var responseObj = {};
  asyncTasks.push(insertTweets.bind(null,10476462));


  async.series(asyncTasks, function(error){
    if(error){

    }
    res.send(response);
  })


tweet.get('statuses/user_timeline', { screen_name:'adamdangelo', count: 10}, function(err, data, response) {
cosole.log(data);
})


 function insertTweets(userId,cb){
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

     var t={user_id:10476462, tweet_id:i,tweet: data[i].text};

     con.query("INSERT INTO `tweets` SET ?",t,
      function(err,data,response){
         if(err){console.log('Error in inserting'+err); return err;}
            console.log('Tweets inserted');
         })
      }    
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using callback:

```
tweet.get('statuses/user_timeline', { screen_name:'adamdangelo', count: 10}, function(err, data, response) {
cosole.log(data);
})
```

just use it as a Promise:

```
tweet.get('statuses/user_timeline', { screen_name:'adamdangelo', count: 10})
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('caught error', err.stack)
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log('response', result)
  })
```

So you can push it to your `asyncTasks`, e.g.:

```
asyncTasks.push(tweet.get('statuses/user_timeline', { screen_name:'adamdangelo', count: 10}))
```

or to make it more readable:

```
var getTweets = tweet.get('statuses/user_timeline', { screen_name:'adamdangelo', count: 10})
asyncTasks.push(getTweets)
```

Comment: it gives an error
TypeError: fn is not a function
   at /usr/lib/nodejs/async.js:610:21
   at /usr/lib/nodejs/async.js:249:17